# Make error installing Ruby 1.9.2 via rvm OSX Lion 10.7.2 XCode 4.2

Tags: rvm, osx-lion, ruby-1.9.2, xcode4.2

I'm getting the following error when trying to install 1.9.2 with rvm

```
/Users/craigspaeth/.rvm/scripts/functions/utility: line 152: date: command not found
Installing yaml to /Users/craigspaeth/.rvm/usr
/Users/craigspaeth/.rvm/scripts/functions/utility: line 152: date: command not found
ERROR: Error running 'make install', please read /Users/craigspaeth/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p290/yaml/make.install.log
```

And here is the yaml/configure.log

```
[] make install
Making install in include
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
test -z "/Users/craigspaeth/.rvm/usr/include" || ../config/install-sh -c -d "/Users/craigspaeth/.rvm/usr/include"
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644  yaml.h '/Users/craigspaeth/.rvm/usr/include/.'
Making install in src
test -z "/Users/craigspaeth/.rvm/usr/lib" || ../config/install-sh -c -d "/Users/craigspaeth/.rvm/usr/lib"
 /bin/sh ../libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c   libyaml.la '/Users/craigspaeth/.rvm/usr/lib'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libyaml-0.2.dylib /Users/craigspaeth/.rvm/usr/lib/libyaml-0.2.dylib
libtool: install: (cd /Users/craigspaeth/.rvm/usr/lib && { ln -s -f libyaml-0.2.dylib libyaml.dylib || { rm -f libyaml.dylib && ln -s libyaml-0.2.dylib libyaml.dylib; }; })
../libtool: line 941: ln: command not found
../libtool: line 941: rm: command not found
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libyaml.lai /Users/craigspaeth/.rvm/usr/lib/libyaml.la
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libyaml.a /Users/craigspaeth/.rvm/usr/lib/libyaml.a
libtool: install: chmod 644 /Users/craigspaeth/.rvm/usr/lib/libyaml.a
../libtool: line 941: chmod: command not found
make[2]: *** [install-libLTLIBRARIES] Error 127
make[1]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

I'm on OSX lion 10.7.2 with XCode 4.2. I've tried adding `export CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2` to my bash_profile, but it didn't help.

Has anyone else run into this? I'm about to go completely bald pulling my hair out for this.

EDIT: Silly me I didn't have the gcc standalone installed? Either way I'm now getting the new errors above.

Comment: This works with me on ruby 1.9.3 mac lion 10.7.2 xcode 4.2

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032824/cant-install-ruby-under-lion-with-rvm-gcc-issues][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032824/cant-install-ruby-under-lion-with-rvm-gcc-issues

Comment: This works with me on ruby 1.9.3 mac lion 10.7.2 xcode 4.2

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032824/cant-install-ruby-under-lion-with-rvm-gcc-issues][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032824/cant-install-ruby-under-lion-with-rvm-gcc-issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error has been fixed in 1.9.2-head ... so just

```
rvm install 1.9.2-head && rvm use 1.9.2-head --default
```

I'm finding 1.9.3 isn't compatible with a lot of the libraries I use yet. This works with Xcode 4.2.

Answer (score 2):

With a clean install of xcode 4.2 you may install ruby 1.9.2 via rvm, though it is unsupported and may cause issues with some native gems, by using this command:

```
rvm install 1.9.2 -C --with-gcc=clang
```

This was noted on rvm issues list here:

https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/610

Answer (score 0):

I just went to install rvm for the first time, which worked. It spits out a warning about ruby 1.9.2, so i built and installed 1.9.3, using (I am on 10.7.2, with Xcode 4.2)

```
rvm install 1.9.3 && rvm use 1.9.3 --default
```

Worked fine. But heroku does not have support in cedar for 1.9.3 yet (or at least they don't claim it), so i really wanted to run 1.9.2. So i tried:

```
rvm install 1.9.2 && rvm use 1.9.2 --default
```

And it also worked... So I am not sure what happened 'right' here. I have Xcode 4.2 installed in the default location, but I also have Xcode 4.1 installed in 'Developer4.1'. I installed 4.2 after I renamed my 4.1 install. Hope this helps someone.

```
    ruby-1.9.2-p290 - #extracting ruby-1.9.2-p290 to /Users/tandersen/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p290
    ruby-1.9.2-p290 - #extracted to /Users/tandersen/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p290
    Fetching yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/tandersen/.rvm/archives
    Extracting yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/tandersen/.rvm/src
    Configuring yaml in /Users/tandersen/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
    Compiling yaml in /Users/tandersen/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
    Installing yaml to /Users/tandersen/.rvm/usr
    ruby-1.9.2-p290 - #configuring 
    ruby-1.9.2-p290 - #compiling 
    ruby-1.9.2-p290 - #installing 
    Removing old Rubygems files...
    Installing rubygems-1.8.10 for ruby-1.9.2-p290 ...
    Installation of rubygems completed successfully.
    ruby-1.9.2-p290 - adjusting #shebangs for (gem irb erb ri rdoc testrb rake).
    ruby-1.9.2-p290 - #importing default gemsets (/Users/tandersen/.rvm/gemsets/)
    Install of ruby-1.9.2-p290 - #complete 
    Using /Users/tandersen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290
    Snow-Pro:~ tandersen$ 

    Snow-Pro:~ tandersen$ irb
    ruby-1.9.2-p290 :001 > x = 3
    => 3 
    ruby-1.9.2-p290 :002 > x*x
    => 9
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing a clean install of xcode 4.2 it will not work.  For those who are indicating they are getting 4.2 to work I would suggest that they had installed 4.2 over the top of 4.1 which as per apples documentation will only install the unix tools once..  So make sure you know what is already installed on your system.

UPDATE for you

Mar 21

I have installed and tested with the following

1. Download and install xCode 4.3.2
2. Download and Install Command line Tools for Xcode late March 2012
3. Set xcode path $ xcode-select -switch /Application/xcode.app/Content/Developer
4. Install Homebrew and then install git, autoconf, automake, libyaml,
   libksba, wget via Brew.
5. Install RVM make sure it is setup in you shell
6. rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p125

There are articles out there recommending this for ruby >=1.9.3 and thats all I have tested and currently use.  I did install and use mysql2, sqlite, and the usual suspect (GEMs) They all compiled and passed some of my basic tests

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Do not use Xcode 4.2. It currently has problems building manuy of the rubies and native-extension gems, as well as Homebrew and MacPort builds. This is due to the change over to LLVm that Apple has made. This is a compiler issue, not an RVM issue. Please use, at most, Xcode 4.1 plus any patches Apple has provided for the 4.1 series.

Comment: Should still be in the AppStore, or you might have to find a torrent for it or something, unfortunately.

Comment: ```rvm get head``` 
or 
```rvmsudo rvm get head``` 
if you're using a multi-user install. 

Then read ```rvm requirements``` to get the URL